# Custom x-headers are removed after the message is sent in Outlook desktop

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, office-addins

I'm working on Outlook add-in. My environment is:

Windows 10 Pro version is 21H2, OS build 19044.1469

Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019

Microsoft® Outlook® 2019 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20234) 32-bit

node v14.18.3 32-bit

The Add-in sets some custom Internet headers based on the options selected by user.
I use EWS UpdateItem operation to set the headers:

```
<UpdateItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite">
  <ItemChanges>
    <t:ItemChange>
      <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADl3V8iAAA=" 
        ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADlMLgM"/>
      <t:Updates>
        <t:DeleteItemField>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="x-custom-header1" PropertyType="String"/>
        </t:DeleteItemField>            
        <t:SetItemField>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="x-custom-header2" PropertyType="String"/>
          <t:Message>
            <t:ExtendedProperty>
              <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="x-custom-header2" PropertyType="String"/>
              <t:Value>yes</t:Value>
            </t:ExtendedProperty>
          </t:Message>
        </t:SetItemField>                                                         
      </t:Updates>
    </t:ItemChange>
  </ItemChanges>
</UpdateItem>
```

The response is:

```
<m:ResponseMessages>
  <m:UpdateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
    <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
    <m:Items>
      <t:Message>
        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGQ2NjU3NGQ2LTFjMGItNGM1ZC1hMjMzLTM1YjUzYzYyZDY3NABGAAAAAABOqCUOqEzcRIky8XqnjNqxBwCNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AAAAAAEPAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADl3V8iAAA=" 
          ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAACNVxNVF2AuQZAWaNgbSGc1AADlMLgP"/>
      </t:Message>
    </m:Items>
    <m:ConflictResults>
      <t:Count>0</t:Count>
    </m:ConflictResults>
  </m:UpdateItemResponseMessage>
</m:ResponseMessages>
```

The OWA works fine.

Compose message -> open Add-in, select the option -> send email -> Open sent item (custom headers are in place)

The problem occurs in Outlook desktop when the sent item doesn't contain any custom headers.

In Outlook desktop (**Cached Mode is disabled**):

Failed case:

Compose message -> open Add-in, select the option -> send email -> Open sent item (**message doesn't have custom headers**)

Successful case:

Compose message -> open Add-in, select the option -> Close compose window (item saved as a draft) -> Open draft item (custom headers are in place) -> send draft item -> Open sent item (custom headers are in place)

Is any way to fix compose->send scenario?

Comment: What event handler do you use for setting up headers?

Comment: I set the internet headers through EWS requests mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync